# Does one need getters and setters for calculation methods?

Tags: class, methods, getter-setter

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BeerStoreBP
{

private String name;

private double custAge;

private double numBeers = 0;

private double beerDisc = 0;

private double beerType = 0;

private double theBeerBrand;

private double total = 0;

private double beer = 0;

```
public void setAge(double theAge)
{
    custAge = theAge;
}

public void setName(String theName)
{
    name = theName;
}

public void setNumBeers(double theNumBeers)
{
    numBeers = theNumBeers;
}

public void setBeerType(double theBeerType)
{
    beerType = theBeerType;
}

public double getAge()
{
    return custAge;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public double getNumBeers()
{
    return numBeers;
}

public double calcNumBeersValid()
{

    String numBeersStr;

    while (numBeers < 3 || numBeers > 6)
    {
        numBeersStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You must pick 3-6 " +
                                                                "beers");
        numBeers = Double.parseDouble(numBeersStr);
    }

    return numBeers;
}

public double calcBeerPrice()
{

    final double LAGIMRED = 1.90;  
    final double DESINIPA = 2.00;
    final double BELBEBRN = 1.80;
    final double SCHOATST = 2.50;
    final double BOULFHSAISN = 2.75;
    final double GANDANCPRTR = 1.75;


       if (theBeerBrand == 1)
           beer = LAGIMRED;

       else if (theBeerBrand == 2)
           beer = DESINIPA;

       else if (theBeerBrand == 3)
           beer = BELBEBRN;

       else if (theBeerBrand == 4)
           beer = SCHOATST;

       else if (theBeerBrand == 5)
           beer = BOULFHSAISN;

       else 
           beer = GANDANCPRTR;        

       return beer;


public double calcBeerTotal()
{
    String beerTypeStr;
    double count = 1;

    while (count <= numBeers)
    {    

    beerTypeStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose between " 
                + "these fine selections:\n1 - Lagunitas Imperial Red - " +
                       "$1.90\n2 - Deschutes Inversion IPA - $2.00\n3 - " +
                 "Bell's Best Brown Ale - $1.80\n4 - Schlafly's Oatmeal " +
                 "Stout - $2.50\n5 - Boulevard's Farmhouse Saison - $2.75" 
                + "\n6 - Gandy Dancer Porter - $1.75");
        beerType = Double.parseDouble(beerTypeStr);
        beerType = theBeerBrand;
        total += beer;
        count++;
    }    

    return total;

}

public double getBeerTotal()
{
    double theTotal;
    theTotal = total; 

    return theTotal;
}

public double calcBeerDisc()
{

    if (numBeers == 6)
        beerDisc = .10;

    else if (numBeers >= 4)
        beerDisc = .05;

    else 
        beerDisc = .00; 

    return beerDisc;
}

public double calcFinalPrice()
{

   double finalPrice;

    finalPrice = total-(total * beerDisc);

    return finalPrice;

}
```

Noob here, so please shed some mercy. The point of the above program is to gather the amount of beers(must be 3-6), provide the customer with a choice for each beer, calculate the total amount of beers, and apply a discount(depends on # of beers). Pretty simple stuff, yet I've hit a brick wall.

My problem lies with calculating the final price. I can't seem to figure out why nothing from by calcBeerTotal method is getting passed to my calcFinalPrice method. My output displays the amount of beers just not the final price.

So my main question is: do I need some sort of setter and getter method for my calc methods? I've tried some setter and getter methods and I still wasn't getting a final price (method located above calcBeerDisc). I'm of limited programming knowledge so please keep from getting any more complicated than what I've written. If it's something aside from setters and getters please keep away from arrays and the like as I do not fully understand them either. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BeerStoreBP {

private String name;

private double custAge;

private double numBeers = 0;

private double beerDisc = 0;

private double total = 0;

// This only exists in one method.  There is no need for it to be global
//private double beerType = 0;

// This only exists in one method.  There is no need for it to be global    
//private double theBeerBrand;

// This only exists in one method.  There is no need for it to be global    
//private double total = 0;

// This only exists in one method.  There is no need for it to be global
//private double beer = 0;

public void setAge(double theAge)
{
    custAge = theAge;
}

public void setName(String theName)
{
    name = theName;
}

public void setNumBeers(double theNumBeers)
{
    numBeers = theNumBeers;
}

// Your functionality is parsed by your dialog.  There is no need for this.
//public void setBeerType(double theBeerType)
//{
//    beerType = theBeerType;
//}

public double getAge()
{
    return custAge;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public double getNumBeers()
{
    return numBeers;
}

public double calcNumBeersValid()
{

    String numBeersStr;

    while (numBeers < 3 || numBeers > 6)
    {
        numBeersStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You must pick 3-6 " +
                                                                "beers");
        numBeers = Double.parseDouble(numBeersStr);
    }

    return numBeers;
}

public double calcBeerPrice(int beerBrand)
{

    final double LAGIMRED = 1.90;  
    final double DESINIPA = 2.00;
    final double BELBEBRN = 1.80;
    final double SCHOATST = 2.50;
    final double BOULFHSAISN = 2.75;
    final double GANDANCPRTR = 1.75;


    double beerPrice;

       if (beerBrand == 1)
           beerPrice = LAGIMRED;

       else if (beerBrand == 2)
           beerPrice = DESINIPA;

       else if (beerBrand == 3)
           beerPrice = BELBEBRN;

       else if (beerBrand == 4)
           beerPrice = SCHOATST;

       else if (beerBrand == 5)
           beerPrice = BOULFHSAISN;

       else 
           beerPrice = GANDANCPRTR;        

       return beerPrice;

}

public void calcBeerTotal()
{
    String beerTypeStr;
    double count = 1;
    double beerPrice;
    // No need to be double
    int beerBrand;

    while (count <= numBeers)
    {    

        beerTypeStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose between " 
                + "these fine selections:\n1 - Lagunitas Imperial Red - " +
                       "$1.90\n2 - Deschutes Inversion IPA - $2.00\n3 - " +
                 "Bell's Best Brown Ale - $1.80\n4 - Schlafly's Oatmeal " +
                 "Stout - $2.50\n5 - Boulevard's Farmhouse Saison - $2.75" 
                + "\n6 - Gandy Dancer Porter - $1.75");
        beerBrand = Integer.parseInt(beerTypeStr);
        beerPrice = calcBeerPrice(beerBrand);
        total += beerPrice;
        count++; 

    }

}

public double getBeerTotal()
{
    return total;
}

public double calcBeerDisc()
{

    if (numBeers == 6)
        beerDisc = .10;

    else if (numBeers >= 4)
        beerDisc = .05;

    else 
        beerDisc = .00; 

    return beerDisc;
}

public double calcFinalPrice()
{

   double finalPrice;

    finalPrice = total-(total * beerDisc);

    return finalPrice;

}


}
```

This is in a working state, but may I recommend you take the UI portions out of this class and include them elsewhere.

Comment: I've tried what you've posted and I'm still not getting a final price. Does beer being a global variable, or any of them, affect values passing between methods?

Comment: I didn't change any code, I only added comments.  Edit:  I changed some code

Comment: I meant I changed theBeerBrand in my calcBeerPrice method to beerType and eliminated the beerType = theBeerBrand statement. Still no bueno. edit: I'll try this out real quick, thanks.

Comment: It worked!! Just so I fully understand what you wrote, did not having a way to invoke the calcBeerPrice method keep me from passing values to that method?

Comment: The values were set, but if you do not call the method nothing will happen.

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks again.